# The readText method catches an exception

Tags: android, api, kotlin, openweathermap

My method readText catches an exception each time i use it, readBytes doesn'twork either. I verified i authorized internet in my manifest and everything should work.

response = URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherq=vernon,fr&units=metric&appid=****").readText(Charsets.UTF_8)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you edit your question to include the full text of the exception that you see? Without that, it's difficult to know what's wrong.

Comment: You should probably delete and repost the question (with your code!) because you included a private key, and it's a bad idea to have those visible on public forums (I edited it but it's still in the history)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

First of all i dont care about the key because its a free one but still thank you. I've found the answer to my question : you need to write `URL(whatever url you are using).readText(UTF_8)`

Comment: Mark the answer as the solution